# select column in R with condition

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame as follows

```
   V2      V4      V6      V8    
1  5       5.2     5.1     4.8
2  4.4     4.1     4.5     4.3
3  4.2     3.8     4.2     4.1
4  5       3.2     3.3     4.0
```

In actual data V value goes from V2 to V200 and row goes from 1 to 99. I want to select columns if its values ever goes less than 4.

Result should be,

```
    V4      V6        
1   5.2     5.1    
2   4.1     4.5     
3   3.8     4.2     
4   3.2     3.3
```

Also want to select columns whose value never goes less than 4. Result should be

```
   V2      V8    
1  5       4.8
2  4.4     4.3
3  4.2     4.1
4  5       4.0
```

I am trying with subset command, but not able to get it done yet.

Comment: maybe `dat[,colSums(dat < 4) > 0]` -- I guess your second one would be `dat[,colSums(dat < 4) == 0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified whether you want to do this for each row or for the whole `data.frame`. For a full `data.frame`:

```
mins <- sapply(df, min)
moreThan4 <- df[which(mins > 4)]
lessThan4 <- df[which(mins < 4)]
```

Comment: I get this error "undefined columns selected". I want it to do on whole data.frame

Comment: This should work. Not sure why the error. I have tried it at my and.

Comment: Works for me. @user3311147 This should work for you, was well - please double-check whether your test code contains any additional errors.

Comment: It works, but the output is not a data.frame. I want to retain the input format for the output.